# Git: Connect existing local repository to existing remote repository

Tags: git, github, git-remote, git-fetch

This is probably pretty basic, but I wasn't able to figure it out yet:

I have a PHP project running on two servers, let's refer to those as `Live` and `Staging`
Both servers are running the same project obviously but with some changes.
The project was not on Github when It got into my hands, so that's what I am trying to do first now.

I managed to create a new remote repository on Github and connect the `Live` System to it.
 (by adding the Github repo as 'origin' on `Live`)
`git remote add origin https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git`

So the Live System is currently on the `master`branch and up to date with `origin/master`which has a history of 4 commits.

Now I am trying to connect the Github Repo on `Staging` as well

So I did a

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git
git remote -v

origin  https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git (push)

git fetch
```

Now when I do a git status I see that the repo is still on Initial commit and all files and folders are listed as untracked:

> ```
>  root@staging-host:/var/www/html# git status
>  On branch master
>
>  Initial commit
>
>  Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be
>  committed)
>
>          .htaccess
>          README.md
>          _index.html
>          api/
>          app/
>          composer.json
>          global/
>          index.php
>          package-lock.json
>          package.json
>          phpinfo.php
>          system/
>          vendor/
>          view/
> ```

How can I check for local changes compared to the last commit in `origin/master`
I don't want to loose any of the local changes but also not to commit or push anything
I need to check the diff first before I decide file by file what to commit and what to reset

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach was almost correct. Take a look at your command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git
```

This tries to add a remote repo as origin and fails, because that already exists.

Run

```
git remote -v
```

You will see that it's your live repo. Name it differently, like

```
git remote add staging https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git
```

and then it should work. If origin is live and staging is staging, then pulling, pushing to staging is the following:

```
git pull staging <branch>
```

and

```
git push staging <branch>
```

respectively. If I were you, I would prefer origin to point to staging and another remote called live would point to live, because you will use staging more frequently.

EDIT

Apparently I have misunderstood the problem. Basically there is a repo hosted by GitHub and you want to use that for staging as well. You do not need to run

```
git init
```

nor to add remotes in that case. You will just need to clone the repo, like

```
git clone https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git
```

Comment: Maybe I am not getting this correctly right now, or that's just the wrong way to do it but what I am currently trying is to have both Live and Staging Push and Pull to the remote Repository which is on Github, not each other. When I run a `git remote -v`I get this output: origin  https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/path-to-repo/repo.git (push)
I also added this to my original post.
I basically added the remote repo as origin in both live and staging system.
This wasnt a problem on live because at that point origin was empty and I could just commit.

Comment: @Chaz live and staging are two separate remotes. You identify a remote by its name. You wanted to identify both live and staging as origin, but then origin is no longer identifying them. If both are origin, then you cannot push to only one of them via git push origin master. You will need to identify them via different names. If you want to push/pull to/from both a the same time, then you can write a shell script for that purpose. But a remote should remain a single remote.

Comment: The way I have this set up there are not live and staging added as remotes somewhere. Staging and live are servers running the project and the github repo is added as remote (origin) on both of them, so they can push/pull to/from the github, not each other

Comment: @Chaz I realized I initially misunderstood your situation. Now I think I understand your problem. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Does this work when there are already files in the folder I want to clone into?
Because that's the whole point here unfortunately.
And I always thought it wasn't.
But I didn't try yet tbh and unfortunately cannot try right now.
But I'll check that later.
Thanks

Comment: @Chaz doing this clone stuff is a one-time affair. Once you do it properly and then you will never have to worry about that again. Assuming that you have a folder called foo with some files, you can clone stuff into the folder bar, then apply the changes you want there, possibly by copying files from folder foo into folder bar. Once all this is done, remove folder foo and rename folder bar to foo.

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is a better way but this should work.

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m 'tmp'`
3. `git diff HEAD origin/master`
4. `git reset --soft HEAD~1`

you can just reset commit you did for checking the difference

Comment: This seems to work indeed, at least I was able to check the diff. I moved to a new branch temp though before committing.
Now when I try to reset I get this: 
`fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'``
I am tempted to just wipe the repo, pull everything from origin to be up to date with origin/master and live and then copy staging code back in from a backup I made.
I just thought there had to be an easier way

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing local repo and an existing remote, you can just set the remote url:

```
git remote set-url <name> <newurl>
```

example:

```
git remote set-url origin http://github.com/myproject.git
```